# Why is `lsof` so slow on macOS 10.13 (High Sierra)?

Tags: command-line, high-sierra, filesystem, macos

This is related to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81140/why-is-lsof-on-os-x-so-ridiculously-slow/243269?noredirect=1#comment412641_243269), but I am on OSX 10.13.4. `lsof` takes about a minute to run, even with the `-n` option on.

I can't even run `dtruss` to examine the system calls being made:

```
$ sudo dtruss sudo lsof
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

dtrace: failed to execute sudo: dtrace cannot control executables signed with restricted entitlements
```

So, why is it taking so long? How can I speed it up?

Comment: I would suggest bolding the fact that you are on High Sierra. Almost flagged as duplicate. Additionally, quote the part in the answer where it says "from....to.....".

Comment: @Josh, Well, the version number was in the title, and the tags, but I've clarified now. :-) I only opened this because a moderator told me to open a new question when I commented on the other question.